# phpMyAdmin Gives error #1064 when trying to edit or delete a row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a database connected to Unity through a php script. This script lets me register an account and set it on a row on the database. So whenever I make a new account it creates a new row in my "Users" table.

Now my problem is that I get an error whenever I try to edit or delete a row **by clicking on the edit or delete icon** in phpmyadmin. If i try to create a query manually it works in phpmyadmin, but the query that the phpmyadmin tries to execute when I click the icon isn't.

```
SQL query: Documentation Edit


SELECT * FROM `UserData`.`Users` WHERE ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near '' at line 1
```

When I try to manually execute the similar correct query it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `UserData`.`Users` WHERE ID = 1 ;
```

Does anyone know the cause of this problem or maybe know a fix for it?

[My server version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EUj4.jpg)

Comment: Show your Update/Delete query. Preferably as text, not an image.

Comment: When you use WHERE, you need to specify something. If you want all rows, then leave off the WHERE. Though this is not the update/delete that you were talking about. I'd suggest starting with looking over the [SQL commands](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-commands/), and reading up on the basic syntax.

Comment: I have the same problem, using phpmyadmin on MAC. I think the problem is not so much supplying an incorrect query, because we're using the graphical interface for editing or deleting; i.e. either the query gets submitted incorrectly by the interface, or the database is simply corrupted? @Plurper, did you resolve this?? Thanks!

Comment: Still not sure yet but I think that the library is correct - it works fine with an older phpmyadmin version and an old mac, which were also used to generate this libaray. So I think there is a clash with either the phpmyadmin and my os version (or, but I think this is less likely, with the library being written in some older version of sql).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the work around that worked for me was using the SQL shell tab with the corresponding SQL code for whatever I want to do - the error only occurs when I use the icons. Thus I think this must be a problem with the interface of phpmyadmin/icons. This is annoying, but at least I haven't lost my SQL library.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd be keen to know. (I'm using phpmyadmin 4.5.6.2 on a Mac Os X 10.10.2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your tables without capital letters. Name them like `userdata` or `user` and so on...